# Visual Studio does not show properties of older projects

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2017

I'm going through several generations of Visual Studio in the last years and have projects which were not migrated. So I'm sticking with some VS2010 projects. I faced [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45208165/visual-studio-2017-does-not-show-properties-of-vs-2010-projects) now and like to know if anyone has a prooper solution. Sidenote: It's the same on opening 2013 projects with 2017 and also with 2010 projects in 2013. It might be in other constellations as well. The properties file does not show any *obvious* setting for regional dependencies.

Comment: Which file shows the issue? Solution .sln file or project file .vcxproj?

Comment: good comment: its the project itself. The solution properties are visibel in both languages